# Alternative to Windows InterlockedIncrement64 using c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, interlocked-increment

I'm using InterlockedIncrement64 in my application for atomic increment to make sure it is thread safe, My code is required to be based only on c runtime library, I decided to use the [atomic class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) I wrote the following 2 methods

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include "time.h"
using namespace std;

void InterLockedIncrement64(int64_t* input)
{
    /*static*/ atomic<int64_t> ato(*input);
    //ato.store(*input);
    ato.fetch_add(1);
    *input = ato.load();
}
void InterlockedIncrement64_(int64_t* input)
{
    atomic<int64_t> *atomicData = reinterpret_cast<atomic<int64_t>*>(input);
    atomicData->fetch_add(1);
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int64_t count = 0;
    int64_t count_ = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        clock_t c = clock();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000001; i++)
        {
            InterlockedIncrement64_(&count_);
        }
        uint32_t time1 = clock() - c;
        c = clock();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000001; i++)
        {
            InterLockedIncrement64(&count);
        }
        uint32_t time2 = clock() - c;

        cout << "Time 1 = " << time1 << endl;
        cout << "Time 2 = " << time2 << endl;

        char in = cin.get();
        if(in == 'c')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I think that the first method is fine (I need confirmation for this)!, the second method calculated the same result but not in tested in multi-threading but it is faster, the second one is suspicious for me, I need advice from those who have experience.

Comment: I don't see how the first one does *anything* to protect the actual value you want incremented. See [`std::atomic<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic). You basically making a local atomic variable, copying the value from the dereferenced unprotected input parameter, doing a fetch-and-add, then copying back (again unprotected) to the parameter address. There is no atomicity on `*input` on this *at all*.

Comment: You are missing a vital feature of [`InterlockedIncrement64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683615.aspx): *"This function generates a full memory barrier (or fence) to ensure that memory operations are completed in order."* This is a stronger guarantee than you were trying to implement.

Comment: @WhozCraig : you are right, I missed that.

Comment: It may be of some benefit to see a *simple* example of something like [race-condition resolution via std::atomic](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8a2a5ec47038884)

Comment: @WhozCraig : thanks for that example so much it make it more clear, the problem is that I have a class that stores its data as binary in memory and get each type then cast it and do it's operation on it, this class used the InterlockedIncrement to increment a part of that memory that represent the count, I wanted to keep all classes but just provide a method that have the same effect of InterlockedIncrement, I need just thread safe increment/decrement, may I need to use the same as the second method in my question, to do casting, is this ok?